# Incorrect form data posted when using multiple <form> tags in a page

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, twitter-bootstrap, postback

I have a page which uses a Bootstrap modal. On the first load of this page a Bootstrap modal popup is shown which is a remote aspx page being loaded and ask for subscription. This shows up only one time and once closed it is never shown for next 30 days.

On the parent page I have a dropdownlist with **AutoPostBack** set to true.

The Problem is when the first time popup is loaded and closed and I change the dropdown the form is posted to the action to the Page that was loaded in the popup rather than posting the form to which the control belongs to.
The HTML is like this:

```
    <form action="mypage.aspx">
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ID="drpItems" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpItems_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Item1" Value="1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item2</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
    </form>


    <div id="subscriptionModal" class="modal fade subscriptionPopupWrapper" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-replace="true" data-focus-on="input:first">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" id="subscriptionModalContent">
                <form action="popup.aspx">
                 ----- Popup page content loaded dynamically -----
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The form inside **#subscriptionModalContent** div is loaded remotely and shown as a modal.
When this modal form is closed and as soon as the **#drpItems** is changed the auto postback event fires and posts the page appending a url of "/popup.aspx" instead of posting the page to "mypage.aspx".

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?
Any suggestions or help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net webforms usually don't work well with multiple forms on the same page.

Althought, it can work if only one of them is marked with `runat=server`.

Comment: I am actually having a MasterPage that has a <form> tag with runat=server and I am loading another page into a modal using Jquery on demand that is also having a runat=server. If I remove the runat=server from the page, the modal page doesn't loads.

Comment: So we are NOT keeping two form tags with `runat=server` in a single aspx page. We are loading the Html response via jquery into the parent aspx page and the final html is having two form tags.

Comment: Nested forms is also a problem and can lead to unpredictable behaviors.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: Yes but we don't have any nested forms.We have checked this link before.

Comment: Ok, I assumed that your masterpage was wraping it's content within a form.